# How to Iterate Map that contain list in the jquery function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Please help me how to iterate the following in **jquery**.

```
var data={100=[submenu 4, submenu 5, submenu 6],
          120=[submenu 10, submenu 11, submenu 12],
          125=[submenu 19, submenu 20, submenu 21],
          99=[submenu 16, submenu 17, submenu 18], 
          77=[submenu 13, submenu 14, submenu 15],
          70=[submenu 1, submenu 2, submenu 3],
          44=[submenu 7, submenu 8, submenu 9]};
```

I want to iterate the above one based on the ids.....100,120,125............

Comment: You should at first fix your object.

Answer (score 5):

First, check if your `data` object is correct:

```
var data = { "100" : ["submenu 4", "submenu 5", "submenu 6"],
             "120" : ["submenu 10", "submenu 11", "submenu 12"],
             "125" : ["submenu 19", "submenu 20", "submenu 21"],
             "99"  : ["submenu 16", "submenu 17", "submenu 18"], 
             "77"  : ["submenu 13", "submenu 14", "submenu 15"],
             "70"  : ["submenu 1", "submenu 2", "submenu 3"],
             "44"  : ["submenu 7", "submenu 8", "submenu 9"] };
```

Then you may use `for` loop to iterate elements in the object:

```
for (var key in data) {
    console.log(data[key]);
}
```

You may also use jQuery [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key);
});
```

Comment: Then your code is wrong. There is no way to run syntactically wrong code in Javascript, so you will never be able to parse this.

Comment: thanks your response, but I got this data from spring mvc model attribute. my actual code is var data='${test1}';  then how do I change this ?