# how to replace a value in a map in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var temp = { "100" = ["submenu 4", "submenu 5", "submenu 6"],
        "136" = ["submenu 10", "submenu 11", "submenu 12"],
        "125" = ["submenu 19", "submenu 20", "submenu 21"],
        "99"  = ["submenu 16", "submenu 17", "submenu 18"], 
        "77"  = ["submenu 13", "submenu 14", "submenu 15"],
        "70"  = ["submenu 1", "submenu 2", "submenu 3"],
        "4"  = ["submenu 7", "submenu 8", "submenu 9"] };
```

how to replace **=** with **:** symbol ? or how to iterate the above temp in jquery function?

Please give a solution.

Comment: You can't since this isn't a valid JSON object.

Comment: you don't need to use jQuery... you can just re-assign values whenever you want.  `temp['100'] = 'some new value';`

Comment: What you have shown is not valid javascript. You will get an error if you attempt to execute this script. You need to replace the `=` with `:`.

Comment: duplicate question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670840/how-to-iterate-map-that-contain-list-in-the-jquery-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var temp = '{ "100" = ["submenu 4", "submenu 5", "submenu 6"],
        "136" = ["submenu 10", "submenu 11", "submenu 12"],
        "125" = ["submenu 19", "submenu 20", "submenu 21"],
        "99"  = ["submenu 16", "submenu 17", "submenu 18"], 
        "77"  = ["submenu 13", "submenu 14", "submenu 15"],
        "70"  = ["submenu 1", "submenu 2", "submenu 3"],
        "4"  = ["submenu 7", "submenu 8", "submenu 9"] }';
temp = temp.replace(/=/g,":");
temp = JSON.parse(temp);
```

Something like this?

Comment: thanks for reply, it is working perfectly, actually my data is coming from a spring mvc controller. Anyway it is working fine, thank u once again.

Answer (score 1):

This JSON is invalid and you cannot replace '=' in temp, because temp would throw an error upon trying to assign this value to it. Replace it in your code in order to make it work, otherwise you cannot iterate on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no valid solution for this other than to change the `=` signs to `:`. Full stop on that point. That is literally the only way to actually fix this and make it a valid JavaScript object.

If you are getting this from an external source, you can do some regex changes on it. If it's your code, you need to just change the symbols.